# Saturation Point of a magnet given some Parameters

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetics

I know from my hard magnets (the remanent magnetization is very close to the saturated magnetization) the Coercivity \$h_c\$, the energy product \$B-H\$ and the remanent magnetization \$m_{rs}\$. **Is it possible to estimate the value for the saturation field that I must apply?**

[image]

Comment: Use `\$ ... \$` for inline MathJAX on this site.

Comment: Ok, I will do it in future posts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is a model that can help you relate all of the parameters of a magnetic hysteresis curve. There are several papers describing it and numerous codes available to help you fit the data to the model (some written in python).

The model is called the [Jiles Atherton model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jiles-Atherton_model)

There is also a [good description here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/60194/equation-describing-magnetic-hysteresis/72789) on fitting the model.

If you need time series fitting or something else there are other papers if you search Jiles Atherton model or inverse Jiles Atherton Model.

I'm not aware if the parameters will give you \$ H_c\$ directly but you could find that once you fit the model easily.

This is another paper [Jiles–Atherton Magnetic Hysteresis Parameters Identification](http://przyrbwn.icm.edu.pl/APP/PDF/120/a120z3p22.pdf) that will help you fit the parameters to the model, its not trivial, but neither is nonlinear parameter identification.

Comment: That was a useful answer. Yes, I found the python models but they all say something like: 
'It appears that choosing the parameters to match a given material is a chore, but that's another story...', which is what I really need to do. 

I am now looking at http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/MagneticHysteresis/, which is what I need but I am struggling in finding the sources to the modelling.

Comment: The sources to the moduleation? are you talking about driving the material to generate a hysteresis curve? If you like the answer upvote.

Comment: I'm sorry, my bad: I really like the model which I linked, but I am having problems in finding the references that the author of the model uses. I looked for the source code in Mathematica but I don't see where the expressions come from.

Comment: You'll have to email them, they don't provide it, it's probably a variation of the link that I provided above the Jiles Atherton model. Either that or they are just fudging the numbers. The other problem that you will have is parameter fitting which is difficult with a nonlinear model. I have another paper if your interested on this

Comment: Mm I am thinking the same about the Jiles Athernon model variation. I'll try to contact him. I don't think they are doing any cosmetics on the numbers, he's a renown scientist, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S._M._Blinder. 

Thank you a lot and maybe I'll ask you in future for that fitting nonlinear model paper.

Comment: I included it in the answer, good luck